# typeahead shows all or nothing but not the correct results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, typeahead

I'm trying to "search" a json for inhabitants by using typeahead.js in combination with handlebars.js.

On my local development environment (XAMPP) it's working, but no matter what I type into the input field, it will always show all the items of my json.

I copied all of my code to jsfiddle, included the same jquery, typeahead and handlebars versions as I have on my locale machine but in this case no results are shown.

*The json is generated by php's json_encode() function and contains a PDO fetch from MySQL (containing all possible results -> performance).*

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r66a1cen/2/

And this is a part of my .json.

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":"1",
      "Name":"Herrmann",
      "Geburtsdatum":"11.12.1920",
   },
   {  
      "ID":"2",
      "Name":"Elisabeth",
      "Geburtsdatum":"29.03.7789",
   },
   {  
      "ID":"3",
      "Name":"Emanuel",
      "Geburtsdatum":"13.06.5587",
   },
   {  
      "ID":"4",
      "Name":"Fanny",
      "Geburtsdatum":"24.06.1200",
   },
   {  
      "ID":"5",
      "Name":"Isaak",
      "Geburtsdatum":"16.09.0000",
   },
   {  
      "ID":"6",
      "Name":"Johannette",
      "Geburtsdatum":"09.07.0100",
   }
]
```

I don't understand why the code duplicates are working different and why I can't "filter" my results by typing something into the input field.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Johannes

Comment: If MySQL isn't filtering results, it is returning everything no matter what the user types. Typeahead with a remote data source will query that url with each keystroke and display the results that come back (everything in this instance). You need to filter with MySQL based on what the user is typing

Comment: Thank you. So typeahead is only filtering on local sources? Is there any possibility to use my "full" json but filter the elements with typeahead?

Comment: You should be able to load the JSON before you initialize typeahead and use `local` in your Bloodhound configuration.

Comment: I tried this and I get a variable which is an array with json objects in it. So I can't search for strings either. It always shows that no items are displayed.

Comment: I tried easyautocomplete.js and it works now.